# Автопостинг в группу из виджета комментариев вк?

Tags: php, wordpress, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Всем привет.

На сайте есть виджет комментариев ВК https://vk.com/dev/Comments

Как можно сделать, чтоб при добавлении комментария в данный виджет, этот самый коммент автоматически публиковался на стене определенной группы?

Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Данный виджет генерирует [различные события](https://vk.com/dev/widget_comments?f=3.%20%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F): при отправке комментария и при удалении комментария. Вам необходимо отлавливать событие отправки комментария с помощью метода [`VK.Observer.subscribe()`](https://vk.com/dev/openapi_2?f=6.%20%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9) и внутри него делать AJAX-запрос на ваш скрипт импорта комментария в группу ВК:

```
VK.Observer.subscribe('widgets.comments.new_comment', function(num, last_comment, date, sign) {
    // здесь ваш AJAX-запрос
});
```

Внутри AJAX-запроса передайте все 4 параметра, которые вы получите, когда пользователь оставит комментарий (см. [события виджета комментариев](https://vk.com/dev/widget_comments?f=3.%20%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F)), а затем, перед публикацией комментария на стене, проверьте валидность параметра `sign` по схеме `md5($api_secret.$date.$num.$last_comment)`, где `$api_secret` - секретный ключ вашего приложения, узнать который можно в настройках. Это цифровая подпись, гарантирующая, что человек действительно оставил запись в виджете комментариев и не подделал AJAX-запрос. Простыми словами: вам надо проверить, является ли полученный вами MD5-код равен параметру `sign`. Если равен, значит, цифровая подпись валидна, а значит, можно смело постить комментарий на стене группы.